# What is the dynamic range on a film-based x-ray?

Tags: medical-imaging

As the title asks, what is the [dynamic range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_range) on a film-based x-ray? And what are the implications of this for digitally stored x-ray images?

Comment: http://drgstoothpix.com/2011/11/02/digital-radiography-spatial-resolution/ - does that help?

Comment: @GrahamChiu: that page only talks of spatial resolution, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Oh well, pass then.

Comment: I don't know enough to answer this in detail, but I know enough about photography and digital images to give it some broad brushes. The dynamic range of film x-ray is fairly narrow -- much narrower than digital x-rays. The only implications for digital storage of film images are that it could take less storage space than digital images. I would imagine that 8 bits per pixel would be sufficient to accurately encode a film x-ray since that's sufficient to encode most black and white photos. However, I wouldn't be surprised to find that they're stored the same as digital images for simplicity.

Comment: @CareyGregory I always wondered about increasing the dynamic range of imaging modalities.  Specifically, I wondered whether it might be possible—and at all valuable—to combine various CT windows to create a high dynamic range composite that optimised multi-organ visualisation in a single image. It would necessitate mapping multiple densities to a shared grey-level, but application of [Graph Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem) could ensure these don’t exist adjacent.